# Получить объект, которому соответствует данный XAML элемент при привязке

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть вот такой элемент в XAML

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind VM.ListStudents}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Student">
                    <StackPanel Width="250">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"  DoubleTapped="TextBlock_DoubleTapped"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Каждый TextBlock отображает свойство Name объекта класса Student. Таким образом в окне TextBlockов может быть несколько. Как при нажатии на TextBlock можно получить ссылку на объект, который соответствует этому TextBlockу при привязке?

Comment: а как вы пытались? `selecteditem` не срабатывает?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, SelecteItem получает именно объект именно TextBlock'a, а мне нужно получить объект класса Student, который соответствует данному TextBlock'у(к которому он привязан)

Comment: attached properties + "{x:Bind}"

Comment: А можно и Tag="{x:Bind}" а далее берете sender и радуетесь

Comment: Вам не должно хотеться «получить ссылку при нажатии». Нужные данные у вас должны приходить в VM через привязку. Расскажите, чего именно вы хотите добиться.

Comment: В результате мне нужно вывести поля объекта класса Student, который  привязан именно к тому элементу ListBox, на который я кликнул

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во вью-модели завести свойство:

```
public Student SelectedStudent { get; set; }
```

В `GridView` к нему привязаться:

```
<GridView 
    SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```